# Does a complex number have finitely many distinct powers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let's say I have a complex number, $z=a+bi$ such that $z$ is a root of unity. It's clear that $\mathrm {arg}(z)= \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$. Can I conclude that $z$ has $\left|\frac{2\pi}{\mathrm {arg}(z)}\right|$ distinct integral powers?

What can we say if I raise $z$ to real powers rather than integral? And lastly what about complex powers? Will there be finite distinct powers?

Comment: Take $z=2 \in \mathbb{C}$ for example, does it have finitely many integral powers?

Comment: No, it doesn't. What about when we add the imaginary part? Does it change?

Comment: Take $\,z=1+i\,$ then. Seriously, why not try a few simple cases before asking.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. When we plot different powers of the complex number, they go around in a circle overlapping the previous ones but are they distinct? That's my point.

Comment: `When we plot different powers of the complex number, they go around in a circle` No, they don't. Did you forget some other condition, like $\,|z|=1\,$? Then see the posted answer which covers that.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: No problem, but you should edit that into the question, not leave it as just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only case in which there are only finitely many distinct positive integer powers $z^n$ is when $z$ is a [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).  When non-integer powers are allowed, there are always infinitely many.

Comment: Ok, only when $|z|=1$ and we have integral powers that there are finitely many distinct powers. In all other cases, they are infinite. Understood.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi Not quite, if I understand what you're saying correctly. Take $z=e^i$ for instance. Then $z^n=e^{ni}$. If $z^a=z^b$ for integers $a$ and $b$, then $a\equiv b\bmod 2\pi$, which means that $a-b$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, a contradiction if $a\neq b$ since $\pi$ is irrational. The roots of unity are only the complex numbers of the form $$e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}$$for integers $k,n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290694/determining-if-a-complex-number-is-a-root-of-unity This solved my problem.